# No error while testing upcoming security changes to Google OAuth with embedded webview

Tags: ios, oauth, google-oauth

Per Google's latest announcement, they will not support OAuth authorisation from embedded webview
https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html

I use embedded webview from with AppAuth-iOS library from my iOS application and tested the change with suggested bool disallow_webview in query param and not seeing any error. Does this mean my app will continue to work after September 30, 2021 ?

The google blog says
"If you do not see an error message while testing the effect of the new embedded webview policies your app's implementation might not be impacted by this announcement."

On what basis, some apps are allowed to use embedded-webview if there is no error is seen.

Comment: I use a custom user agent string with with embedded WKWebview and if I don't use that, I can see 'disallowed_useragent' error. So seems like we can continue to use embedded webview if we don't use default user agent. If that's the case, how it can help in security perspective.

Comment: Same over here, no error shown on captive portal app where login takes place through embedded webview